# Marklogic 6.0 support windows 32 bit?

Tags: marklogic

Does Marklogic 6.0 support windows 32 bit OS. On their home page, I see it as supported but a DLL is required but rest of thread on other sites show that 32 bit support is not there. Pls confirm..

Or is it something that Marklogic 6.0 can be installed with 32 bit but it may be best for 64 bit and certain features wont work as expected. If so, pls list such features missing.

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 2):

32-bit support is gone for good, as of MarkLogic 6. This is for the best: running in 32-bit environments was always a headache because of the limited address space.

You can still download older 32-bit versions from http://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/5.0 - if you enjoy pain. But it's much better to set up a 64-bit environment, so that you have the latest release and don't have to worry about 32-bit limits. If you have older 32-bit software, run it in compatibility mode, or move it into a VM.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, my intention is to explore MarkLogic and I may not want to do full fledged development, hence my specific question would be will the server come up in 32bit Windows 7 and can do basic operations or it is not possible at all? Thanks

Comment: @user2493557 Find a server with a supported 64-bit OS, find someone that does have 64-bit OS and lend his/her machine, or run a supported 64-bit OS in a VM if necessary. As of MarkLogic 6 there is no installer for 32-bit OS, so that is a no-go..

Answer (score 2):

No - Marklogic 6 on Windows is only supported on 64bit platforms. From the system requirements:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (x64), Windows Vista 64-bit Edition (x64), Windows 7 64-bit (x64)*

I imagine the reference to a 32bit DLL is a holdover from previous versions.