# MarkLogic 7 for Windows 7 for 32 bit. Do we have setup for this?

Tags: marklogic

I want Marklogic 7 Window Server setup in Windows 7 for 32 bit but it is not available on official website but some blog are saying it is possible but they have not given any solution.

Do anyone one have idea?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148687/marklogic-6-0-support-windows-32-bit

Answer (score 1):

As of MarkLogic 6, MarkLogic is no longer distributed as 32-bit. Running the 64-bit version was faster anyhow..

HTH!

Comment: But i want MarkLogic 7  32 bit setup?         Where will i found that.

Comment: If you are quick, you can download MarkLogic 5 32-bit, but a) it will likely get discontinued in near future, and b) you will miss out on lots of goodies. I am pretty sure there were compelling reason to no longer want to support 32-bit..